# Download Drugs & Interactions Database UK

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking to download a database of Drugs, Warnings & Interactions for the UK. Is this information freely available? I was in contact with one company and they wanted €3000 per year. The DailyMed Web Service seems like a good service but only for the USA. I am based in Ireland so UK or Ireland would do.